# setTimeout fazendo perde valor da variável?

Tags: angular, typescript

Vou resumir o código pois o meu está muito grande, vamos lá.Eu tenho uma variável global do tipo boolean que recebe false, ao entrar em um if ela tem que receber no lugar de false o true, porém quando entra no setTimeout o booleano está retornando "undefined" em vez de retorna true. Fiz esse código para vocês entenderem mais ou menos como está ocorrendo, mas o primeiro if não pega por algum motivo.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Memoria3Page } from '../memoria3/memoria3';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-memoria2',
  templateUrl: 'memoria2.html',
})
export class Memoria2Page {
  verificaViradasCima: number = 0;
  cartaViradaCima1: boolean = false;
  cartaViradaCima2: boolean = false;

  cartaViradaBaixo1: boolean = false;
  cartaViradaBaixo2: boolean = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) { 
  }

  fase2(): void{
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(Memoria3Page);
  }
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    console.log("Memoria Fase 2");

    criaTabueliro1();
  }

  gameOver(): void{
    if(document.getElementById("virada0").style.zIndex == "998" && document.getElementById("virada1").style.zIndex == "998" && 
       document.getElementById("virada2").style.zIndex == "998" && document.getElementById("virada3").style.zIndex == "998" &&
       document.getElementById("virada4").style.zIndex == "998" && document.getElementById("virada5").style.zIndex == "998"){
        document.getElementById("nextNivelButton").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("msgFinish").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }

  point(): void{
    document.getElementById("bloqueiaClick").style.zIndex = "995";
    this.verificaViradasCima =0;
    document.getElementById("imgAcerto").className = "pontuacao";
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("imgAcerto").className = "imgAcerto";
    },1500);
    this.gameOver();
  }

  pararParaVerificar(): void{
    if(this.verificaViradasCima == 2){

      console.log(vetor[0] +" "+ vetor[1] +" "+ vetor[2] +" "+ vetor[3] +" "+ vetor[4] +" "+ vetor[5]);
      // Verifica a carta 1
      if(vetor[0] == vetor[1] && this.cartaViradaCima1 == true && this.cartaViradaCima2 == true){
        console.log("ENTROU IF");
        this.cartaViradaCima1 = false;
        this.cartaViradaCima2 = false;
        this.point();

      }

      else{
        console.log("Entrou else"+this.cartaViradaBaixo1+this.cartaViradaBaixo2+this.cartaViradaBaixo3+this.cartaViradaBaixo4+this.cartaViradaBaixo5+this.cartaViradaBaixo6);
        this.verificaViradasCima = 0;

        // Este é o if em que é recebido o this.cartaViradaBaixo1 == true e this.cartaViradaBaixo2 == true porém perde o valor ao entrar no setTimeout mais abaixo
        if(vetor[0] != vetor[1] && this.cartaViradaCima1 == true && this.cartaViradaCima2 == true){
          console.log("Entrou no else, e dps no if 1");
          this.cartaViradaCima1 = false;
          this.cartaViradaCima2 = false;
          this.cartaViradaBaixo1 = true;
          this.cartaViradaBaixo2 = true;
        }

         setTimeout(function(){
          if(vetor[0] != vetor[1] && this.cartaViradaBaixo1 == true && this.cartaViradaBaixo2 == true){
            console.log("Entrou no else setTimeOut, e dps no if 1");
            document.getElementById("bloqueiaClick").style.zIndex = "999";
            document.getElementById("virada0").style.zIndex = "996";
            document.getElementById("virada1").style.zIndex = "996";
            document.getElementById("virada0").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
            document.getElementById("virada1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            this.cartaViradaBaixo1 = false;
            this.cartaViradaBaixo2 = false;

          }

           document.getElementById("bloqueiaClick").style.zIndex = "995";
         },2000)
      }
    };
  };
```

Neste último setTimeout ao fazer ao tentar fazer a condição no IF não é feita com sucesso pois "this.cartaViradaBaixo1 == true && this.cartaViradaBaixo2 == true" não estão retornando true mas sim undefined.

OBS: Não posso utilizar jQuery;

Comment: Mas não tem nada que chame esse `if`. Esses `if`s não teriam que estar dentro da função?

Comment: No meu código original eles estão, ai foi só uma forma reduzida pra vocês tentarem entender mais ou menos como o problema está acontecendo.

Comment: Blz, mas assim não tem como reproduzir o problema. Olhando o código que vc colocou, não parece ter erro algum.

Comment: Tente colocar o código para rodar e veja se o booleano retorna true, vai ver que não por causa da setTimeout, em vez disso vai retorna undefined...

Comment: Eu editei a publicação vê se ficou melhor assim...

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema é a referência ao `this`. Esse é um erro bastante recorrente em JavaScript. O `this` que você usa no callback do `setTimeout` não é necessariamente o mesmo `this` que você tem no contexto de chamada do `setTimeout`.

O callback do `setTimeout` normalmente é invocado com o valor `this` sendo `window` no browser.

Uma solução para o seu problema seria usar `bind`:

```
setTimeout(function () { /* implementação */ }.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 0):

Além do `bind` citado pelo Thiago (que irá afetar o `this`) você pode simplesmente criar uma variavel para se referir ao `this`:

```
var $this = this;

setTimeout(function(){
  if(vetor[0] != vetor[1] && $this.cartaViradaBaixo1 == true && $this.cartaViradaBaixo2 == true){
    console.log("Entrou no else setTimeOut, e dps no if 1");
    document.getElementById("bloqueiaClick").style.zIndex = "999";
    document.getElementById("virada0").style.zIndex = "996";
    document.getElementById("virada1").style.zIndex = "996";
    document.getElementById("virada0").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    document.getElementById("virada1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    $this.cartaViradaBaixo1 = false;
    $this.cartaViradaBaixo2 = false;

  }

   document.getElementById("bloqueiaClick").style.zIndex = "995";
 },2000)
```